# RxJS in combining http requests during component initialization in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have a question. I am starter in RxJS and didn't find answer yet network. Thus, would like to ask you.
**What I need:** I extract a Id from ActivatedRoute and then (on my mind, however not sure) create 2 streams. 1st - will download realted parts for item, and 2nd  - will download main details. Next requests depends on this details.
I perform this logic with code below. Everything works well. However, I am afraid that I wrote not good code as it should be. Maybe somebody could correct me and explain my mistakes. I have some straight questions I put it here and mark with number in code for easier navigation.

1) When I create 2 separate streams it launches router$ twice. Is it important? How I could launch it once and then separate on 2 streams?

2) forkJoin. Acctually I don't need to wait untill all request will be executed. I didn't find proper operator which will emit values without waiting another. And it was good if error on any request does not cancel all another. Is there some another suitable operator?

3)  switchMap or mergeMap? I know that switchMap cancel previous request, but still I don't know which operator is preferable for it.

4) I decided at the end to merge this into 1 subscription and in ngOnDestroy unsubscribe. But maybe it would be better to use subscribe instead of operator map and unsubscribe from each separatly?

Thank you in advance for you answer. If you have any another idea or remarks please shoot. I will be very appriciate!

```
router$ =  this.aRoute.paramMap.map(params => +params.get('id'));        // <----  1

ngOnInit() {
  this.details$ = this.router$.mergeMap(id => {                           // <---- 3
    return this.claimSvc.getClaimDetails(id);
  }).do(details => {
    this.currentDetails = details;
    .... // some borring things            
  }).switchMap(details => {                                              // <---- 3
    return  Observable.forkJoin(                                          // <--- 2
      this.claimSvc.getDocuments(details.date....),
      this.claimSvc.getHolders(details.date...),
      this.claimSvc.getSubTypes(details.date...),
      this.claimSvc.getCategories(details.date...)
    )
  }).map(([documents, holders, subtypes, categories]) => {
    this.documents = documents;
    this.holders = holders;
    this.subTypes = subtypes;
    this.categories = categories;
  });

  this.claimParts$ = this.router$.switchMap(id => {                     // <---- 3
    return Observable.forkJoin(                                         //  < ------ 2
      this.claimSvc.getAttributes(id), 
      this.claimSvc.getParties(id),
      this.claimSvc.getClaimObjects(id),
      this.claimSvc.getClaimInsurances(id),
      this.claimSvc.getClaimPayments(id)
    )
  }).map(([Attribute, Parties, Objects, Insurances, Payments]) => {
    this.attributes = Attribute;
    this.parties = Parties;
    this.objects = Objects;
    this.insurances = Insurances;
    this.payments = Payments;
  });

  this.subscription = Observable.merge(this.claimParts$, this.claimDetails$).subscribe();  // <----  4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a guard
2. Inside guard, have 2 functions each firing one request and returning Observable from it
3. In guards `CanActivate` method do something like this:

.

```
FireFirstRequest(): Observable<boolean> {
///get your data and save it somewhere (shared service or something)
///and return Observable<boolean> (true) when done
}

FireSecondRequest(): Observable<boolean> {
///get your data and save it somewhere (shared service or something)
///and return Observable<boolean> (true) when done
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
   const combined = Observable.zip(
   this.FireFirstRequest(),
   this.FireSecondRequest(),
   (a, b) => a && b
   );

   return combined;
}
```

4. In route definitions, use the guard to protect that route/component

`Observable.zip` makes sure it returns `true` only when each inner `Observable` has emmited and they are both `true` (`a&&b`).

Comment: thank you @dee zg, so you propose not to open component if it does not get data? I can extract id from params in Guard as in component?

Comment: well, if component needs some data before it makes sense to make an instance of it then yes, it should not open before you have data. Yes, you can extract any route data in guard. just inject activeRouteSnapshot in guard.

Comment: hm, but actually each route navigate and component swap request a some data from server. Is that mean that all navigation in app should be done with CanActivate guard or Resolve?

Comment: yes, thats what i do. it depends on your usecase, depends if you cache data, if you distinguish first and subsequent component openings...but in general yes, my default approach is to get data in canactivate/resolver and then if there is some special case i deviate from that.